# How to store Primitive Datatypes , Strings in a HBase Column and Retrieve Them Using Serialization and Deserialization?

Tags: serialization, hbase, deserialization, primitive-types

How to store Primitive Datatypes , Strings in a HBase Column and Retrieve Them. Normally when we want to store data in HBase table we do as below.

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
HTable table = new HTable(conf, "people");
Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("doe-john-m-12345"));
put.add(Bytes.toBytes("personal"), Bytes.toBytes("givenName"), Bytes.toBytes("John"));
put.add(Bytes.toBytes("personal"), Bytes.toBytes("mi"), Bytes.toBytes("M"));
put.add(Bytes.toBytes("personal"), Bytes.toBytes("surame"), Bytes.toBytes("Doe"));
put.add(Bytes.toBytes("contactinfo"), Bytes.toBytes("email"), Bytes.toBytes("john.m.doe@gmail.com"));
table.put(put);
table.flushCommits();
table.close();
```

My question is how to Store Primitive data types in HBase including Strings and How to retrieve them using serialization and derialization. I'm really new to HBase and please give me a clear steps to get this job done.

Answer (score 0):

check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237274/is-this-method-for-hbase-data-storage-correct)

You can use `Bytes` in `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util`

like:

```
byte[] longBytes = Bytes.toBytes(2l);

long l = Bytes.toLong(longBytes); 

System.out.println(l); // <-- this should give you 2l
```