# Is this method for HBase data storage correct?

Tags: serialization, hbase, deserialization

Here what is want to do is i want to store and retrieve serialized data in HBase table and later i want to retrieve them as it is. I thought to follow method. Please tell me if i'm wrong.

```
put.add(streamColumnFamily,streamColumnName,serializedData);
```

Here serializedData  attribute will be handle by [HBaseSerialization](https://github.com/tellapart/TellApart-Hadoop-Utils/blob/master/src/java/com/tellapart/cascading/hbase/HBaseSerialization.java) class. what is want to is, is this method correct. will i be able to retrieve stored data as it was. (int as int, float as float, String as String etc)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the method is correct. HBase stores everything in bytes. 
You basically do something like

```
byte[] key = createSomeKey();

Put put = new Put(key);
put.add(streamColumnFamily,streamColumnName,serializedData); 

HTable h = .... // create HTable from HAdmin 

h.put(put);
```

You can also use native java serialization mechanism for serializing and deserializing objects like this:

```
   public byte[] serialize(Serializable object) throws IOException {


      ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

      ObjectOutput stream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

      stream.writeObject(object);

      stream.flush();

      return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
    }


public Object deserialize(byte[] bytes){

     ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

     ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);

     objectInputStream.readObject(); 
   }
```

Also if you are serializing and deserializing basic object like Integer,Long, String ... there is a good utility class called `Bytes` in `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util`